# Jquery Radio button can't get the checked one

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, radio-button

I'm new to web programing so I have an issue that I can't get from the Radio group the checked one.

Here is my code:

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-radio">
              <input type="radio" name="quest4" value="30">
                  <div class="icon">
                      <i class="material-icons">filter_1</i>
                    </div>
                  <h5><img src="./images/30.jpg" alt="" width="100px"></h5>
            </div>
        </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-3">
          <div class="choice" data-toggle="wizard-radio">
              <input type="radio" name="quest4" value="50">
                  <div class="icon">
                      <i class="material-icons">filter_1</i>
                    </div>
                  <h5><img src="./images/50.jpg" alt="" width="100px"></h5>
            </div>
        </div>
  </div>
                                                
</form>
```

and a capture for the above:

[image]

So i want in jquery to get the checked radio button
I used this code to get

```
quest4 = $('input[name=quest4]:checked').val();
console.log(quest4);
```

but it returns **undefind**

**i found something may help
when i click on a radio the input change to :**

```
<input type="radio" name="quest4" value="50" checked="checked">
```

Comment: Try `quest4 = $('input[name="quest4"]:checked').val();` You forgot the quotes around quest4

Comment: same thing undefid result

Comment: You are calling that code onload ? Working fine check [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4dc0xm6n/) .

Comment: i use a button to et the values. but i think the problem comes from the click. because when i click on radio button the input change to <input type="radio" name="quest4" value="50" checked="checked">
and not like youre exemple <input type="radio" name="quest4" value="50" checked>

Comment: That's not the issue .It will still work .